gcc is giving a warning for implicit declarition of function when header files are included
I learning c, when I compile my program with make it give me a warning for implicit declaration but still runs like it should
These are the warnings I get when I try to compile,
gcc -o bin/final src/file.c src/main.c src/parse.c
src/main.c: In function \u2018main\u2019:
src/main.c:16:14: warning: implicit declaration of function \u2018open_file_rw\u2019 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   16 |         fd = open_file_rw(argv[1]);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.c:20:12: warning: implicit declaration of function \u2018parse_file_header\u2019 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   20 |         if(parse_file_header(fd, &numEmployees))
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


I have a main file with my Makefile, then I have include with all my headers and src with all my c files
Here is my main.c,
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../include/file.h"
#include "../include/parse.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd, numEmployees = 0;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    fd = open_file_rw(argv[1]);
    if(fd == -1)
        return -1;
    
    if(parse_file_header(fd, &numEmployees))
        return -1;

    printf("Number of employees stored: %d\n", numEmployees);
    
    return 0;
}

Here is file.h
#ifdef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

int open_file_rw(char* filename);

#endif /* FILE_H */

Here is file.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "../include/file.h"

int open_file_rw(char* filename)
{
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return fd;
    }

    return fd;
}

Here is parse.h,
#ifdef PARSE_H
#define PARSE_H

struct dbheader
{
    unsigned short version;
    unsigned short count;
};

int parse_file_header(int fd, int* numEmployeesOut);

#endif /* PARSE_H */

and here is parse.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "../include/parse.h"

struct dbheader_t
{
    unsigned short version;
    unsigned short count;
};

int parse_file_header(int fd, int* numEmployeesOut)
{
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Bad file descriptior provided\b");
        return -1;
    }

    struct dbheader_t header = {0};
    if(read(fd, &header, sizeof(header)) != sizeof(header))
    {
        printf("Failed to read file header\n");
        return -1;
    }

    *numEmployeesOut = header.count;
    return 0;
}

and finally here is my Makefile,
TARGET := bin/final
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst src/%*.c, obj/*.c, $(SRC))
INCLUDE := ../include

default: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o
    rm -f bin/*

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $?

obj/%.o : src/%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@ -I$(INLCUDE)

I know this is a long post, Ive been looking at this for hours and cant figure out whats going wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks.
I tried to build my program using make, but keep getting errors.

Don't worry, the post was not too long. You've given all information necessary to reproduce your problem. It is rather a mistake to omit parts of your original source code that you think are irrelevant. It happens very often that the bug is hidden in exactly those parts. So, well done by you!

Please note that it is bad practice to enter paths inside the #include even if they are relative to the main project directory. Avoid that, locating the files is the IDE and linker's business. Decent IDEs can present a directory structure similar to the real directories as you add files to the IDE. Similarly, decent IDEs take care of the linking so that we don't have to manually muck around with make files, as if still living in the year 1990 or something :)

@Matthew.Loder, Do you really want \b in printf("Bad file descriptior provided\b");?  Tip: also run spell checker.

Thank you guys, so much I appreciate the feedback. As for me using a makefile Im doing it on purpose because I want to understand the c compiler. Any advice for how I can avoid using relative paths.

You can avoid that with gcc -Wall -I '/path/to/your/project/include' -c source.c -o source.o. This is usually done in the Makefile. The option -Wall turns on compiler warnings which is very important, especially for beginners. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html for other warning options.

You can give the option -I as many times as you want if you want to add more than one directory to the include search path.

Your header files are broken. You use #ifdef FILE_H and it should be #ifndef FILE_H. Therefore, the header files are empty, when the compiler sees them.
If you suspect that there is something wrong with one of your header files, there are two standard strategies that can help you find the issue.
First option: Add #error directives to see whether they are processed, and how. Something like this:
#error file.h gets included!
#ifdef FILE_H /* Bug! Wrong! */
# define FILE_H 1

#error file.h was processed!
#endif

That will print an error to the console and show you that the file was correctly included.
For more complicated issues, it helps to invoke the preprocessor only, like this:
$ gcc -c -E program.c

That will print the output of the preprocessor, including filename and line number information to the console.  And you would have seen, that the header file is completely empty for the compiler.
To answer your other, implicit question, why the code works although the header file is not processed: It is not necessary to declare functions in C. If you implicitely declare function, the compiler will assume a signature of int FUNCTIONNAME(), i.e. a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer.
It is just not wise to use that "feature" because the compiler is not able to check whether the usage of the function is correct and that can lead to problems. And besides, if the function is really missing, the warning from the compiler is usually easier to understand than the warning from the linker.  Try that out by something like prindf("typo");.

Zuit. I felt that the lines looked oddly short, but did not spot it. Nice one. (Strictly spoken, they do get included, just their content not visible to compiler.... )

There was just one single character missing on the first line. If they immediately look oddly short to you, you must have a very good eye and will become a great C programmer. :)

Their relative shortness to the next line is much more pronounced. By idiom, the #if... and the #de... lines are of identical length. 1 shorter is a noticable eye-sore.

Sorry, @Yunnosch, I had confused you with the OP. You are right. The header files get included (otherwise the compiler would have complained) but are just mostly skipped because of the guard. I've updated the answer. And I usually write the second line with a space after the hash, like # define FILE_H 1, and therefore they looked totally right to my eyes lengthwise.

I can see the reason for your blank in there. It seems there is more than one idiom. Or I am to quick with using that term.

Thank you so much, I will keep an eye out for the #ifndef and #define lines being different lengths. My issue has been fix, although it has been brought to my attention that it is bad practice to use relative file paths for include statements, just wondering how I can avoid this.
